# 301 Moved Permanently PHP Laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

Hi I'm trying to get data from anther site so I used

```
    $url = 'MY_URL' . $route . '/' . $id;
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('url: ACCESS_URL', 'token: TOKEN'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $type);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
```

so I get 301 Moved Permanently output
 I works fine on local machine put after uploading I got that error 
,any suggestions

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you expecting a different code? Do you want to `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`?

Comment: double check on the target machine whether curl is installed properly?

Comment: @kerbholz thanks that was helpful

Comment: Nice to hear, I made it an answer you can accept if you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifically tell cURL to follow redirection:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem with me was missing component `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`